# Magento 2.1.8 - Menu not showing on CMS pages

Tags: magento-2.1, navigation

I created a new Magento store 2.1.8 without sample data. When I added a category under the root category - it will not show on the home page. When I log in as a customer, on `customer_account_index`, I can see the menu.

When I go to the home page, I do not see any grey navigation area like on `customer_account_index`

It seems like on none of the CMS pages, I can see the catalog menu. The settings in

Catalog -> Category Top Navigation -> Depth is set to 10.

Some extra information, it’s the Bitnami configuration.

Comment: Can you see the category menu on the customer account area? This is not a defaulft Magento's behavior. Or you mean the customer account menu?

Comment: I can see the category menu on customer account pages. Not on CMS pages. I also can see it when I search for products

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes. Several times. It appears to be on all cms pages

Comment: @Nikolas it was due to the varnish cache and https :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the cause. It was related to the following bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3897

It has to do with Varnish and the processing of HTTPS urls